# Transfering Data From Production Server To Development Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am want to make the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO [Server_1\Instance_1].[Database].[dse].Table1
SELECT * FROM [Server_2\Instance_2].[Database].[dse].[**Table1**]
```

The point is the tables are on the different servers. I tried with the statement above. However, when I am on server_1 and when I run the following statement in order to retrieve the data from server 2:

```
SELECT * FROM [Server_2\Instance_2].[Database].[dse].[**Table1**]
```

... I get zero rows.
But when I run the statement above on the Server_2, I get a set of rows.

How can I transfer data from production to development server/environments?
I am using MS Management Studio.

**UPDATE**:
The error message I am getting when I run the select statement in order to retrieve the data from another (production) server:

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Prod_Server\Instance" does not contain the table ""Database"."dse"."BoxIteration"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table.

Select statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM [Prod_Server\Instance].[Database].[dse].[BoxIteration]
```

Comment: You have the same server name in both 4 part object names in the first insert statement. Is this a typo in the question?

Comment: may be both the servers are linked servers then the above query will work

Comment: @GarethD: It's a typo. I'll correct it. In essence, the question is about transferring data from one server to another for purpose of testing the solution with production data.

Comment: There is no reason the first query should not work as long as your [servers are linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). What happens when you run this query? Do you get an error? If not how many rows does it say is inserted? If you can't link your servers then SSIS would be a good alternative.

Comment: @GarethD: I updated the question with the error message I am getting

Comment: Use "Import and Export Data" Which is available in Sql server. It is also simple.

Comment: @HbV2: Can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: Next time post the error message first!! Once you fixed your linked server you don't need to use the export/import wizard. You should take the opportunity to learn something and fix your existing error

Answer (score 2):

Two things to take into account:

- add the source server as a linked server in the destination server
- verify that the credentials specified while creating the linked server have access to the data in the source server

I have a localized version of SQL Server, so the transalation may not match what you will see in your screen: open Object Explorer window in SSMS, connect to the destination server, open the tree and look for Server Objects, Linked Servers. Right click on the source linked server, and see the properties. Open the Security pane, and see which credentials are used to connect to the linked server.

Once you do so, you have to check the permissions of that credentials on the source server to verify that it can acccess the table in question.

If you don't understand, or can't do some of the steps (for lack of permissions), get help form your DBA: he will understand and solve the problem at once.

Comment: can you please give an example how to actually do it? Btw, I am developer, and have read permissions on production server, and read+write permissions on dev server.

Answer (score 1):

If u have access(Having credentials) to both prod and dev Db servers you can use "Import and Export Data"
1.Go to start and open "Import and Export Data"
[image]

2. Wizard will open give source server name, credentials and Database(For your case Prod)
3. Then give destination server name, credentials and Database(Dev)
4. Select the table , if there any identity column -->"Edit Mapping" and Enable identity insert.
5. Then give next--> it will start copying.